# not able to run wsadmin command through docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, websphere

DockerFile

```
COPY ./webapps/testserver.war /tmp
RUN wsadmin.sh -lang jython -conntype NONE -c "AdminApp.install('/tmp/testserver.war', '[ -appname testserver -contextroot /testserver -MapWebModToVH [[ testserver.war testserver.war,WEB-INF/web.xml default_host]]]')"
```

when I buid

docker build -t testserver .

Getting below error. any idea?

```
** ASSERTION FAILED ** j9scar.209 at jvm.c:1740 Assert_SC_true((j2seVersion >= 0x1700))
** ASSERTION FAILED ** j9util.41 at vmargs.c:700 Assert_Util_unreachable((0 ))
JVMJ9VM011W Unable to load jclscar_28: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/amd64/compressedrefs/libjclscar_28.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re installed the docker. It is fine now.